# Training a detectron2 model on intel neural compute stick2

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, openvino, detectron

Any one knows how to train `faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x` model which is pytorch-based model from detectron2 models zoo on intel neural compute stick2 device ?
I've already installed `openvino-toolkit` and run correctly one of their demos on my device.
I've trained the `faster_rcnn_R_50_FPN_3x` on a custom data set with detectron2 on `google-colab-gpu` and now I have to train it on the intel neural compute stick2 vpu to compare the AP results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot train models on the Intel Neural Compute Stick 2 (NCS2). NCS2 is to be used with OpenVINO™ toolkit. OpenVINO™ toolkit consists of two main components, which are Model Optimizer and Inference Engine. The Inference Engine MYRIAD plugin has been developed for inference of neural networks on Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2. Have a look on this [OpenVINO™ Toolkit Workflow](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/2021.4/index.html#openvino_toolkit_workflow).